# mootools moopopup url option not working?

Tags: url, popup, mootools, mootools-events, mootools-fx

I'm new to `mootools`, I am working on the demo example for `moopopup` but for me option url to load remote does not pop up.

```
<link href="moopopup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-yc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-more-yc.js"></script>
<script src="moopopup-yc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function runExample3() { 
        var mypopup3 = new moopopup({
            title: 'My home page',
            resizable: false,
            width: 800,
            max_body_height: 600,
            url: 'http://www.google.co.in/'
        });
        mypopup3.display();     
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="prettyPrint()">
<span class="button link" onclick="runExample3();">run javascript</span>
</body>
```

Here is the URL:

http://sasi.pro/searchsn/new/

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't do what you want directly because of cross domain security. You cannot import another website into your own html. You can make ajax requests but you can not import http://www.google.co.in/ via ajax.

I'm not sure of how you will use the moopopup, but the only alternative I see is use the `htmlnode` option of the moopopup and load an `iFrame` into it. In that case it will work and you just have a bit of CSS work left. Still, some websites do not allow showing themselves in a iFrame, Google is one of them.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3FbD4/)**

I made also small changes on your code, note that on your site/link your are calling a function `prettyPrint()` on page load that doesn't exist (maybe part of other code you have)...

Anyway my code in the demo:

HTML

```
<span class="button link">run javascript</span>
<div id="newiframe">
    <iframe src="http://www.yr.no" id="newiframe" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#newiframe {
    display:none;
    width:770px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.moopopup-body #newiframe {
    display:block;
}
```

Script

```
var myIframe = document.id('newiframe');
function runExample3() {
    var mypopup3 = new moopopup({
        title: 'My home page',
        resizable: false,
        width: 800,
        max_body_height: 600,
        html_node: myIframe
    });
    mypopup3.display();
}

document.getElement('.button.link').addEvent('click', runExample3);
//commented because it doesn't exist
// window.addEvent('domready', function() { prettyPrint();});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works first time, the second time i got this error
    TypeError: myIframe is null
I dont know why its happening..

Comment: Also i have changed the iframe url to my server.. 
    <iframe src="http://sasi.pro/searchsn/new/test_content.html" ....

Comment: @sasi, do you want to use content in the moopopup from your domain or other domains?

Comment: I want to open from other domains.